# Drawing map from XY coordinates in CSV and exporting it to JPEG using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, arcpy

I have a csv file containing about 40,000 rows of data with X, Y (longitude and latitude) data. It is US data, and I have downloaded a state.shp file on which the X, Y points can overlay.

I am able to do it by hand on ArcGIS, but referencing two books on ArcPy ('ArcPy and ArcGIS - geospatial analysis with python' and 'Programming ArcGIS with python cookbook') still doesn't give me a good idea of how to do it using python script with Arcpy, because almost all data used in their examples are not .csv.

Note: I would like to not open ArcGIS at all, but save the map as a jpeg file directly in the python script. Any hints will help.

Answer (score 2):

To do this look at the [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) code examples:

> Creates a new point feature layer based on x- and y-coordinates
>   defined in a source table. If the source table contains z-coordinates
>   (elevation values), that field can also be specified in the creation
>   of the event layer. The layer created by this tool is temporary.

You can then use arcpy.mapping.AddLayer() to add your layer or layer file to a map, and then use arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG() to export that map to JPEG.

Comment: I am slower than you as always...

Answer (score 2):

You can replicate the example in [this page about Make XY Event](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000) (standalone script one) . You need to [add resulting layer to an MXD](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/AddLayer/00s300000025000000/) (preferably to a template with desired layout settings) and then [programmatically export to JPEG](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000038000000) after [setting active data frame's extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/) to visible [extent of your layer (i.e., getExtent)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/).

Comment: I will try your suggested links tomorrow. One thing I notice is arcpy seems to have its own dataframe structure, I do want to use pandas data frame as well since I like to create different maps using different slices of sample via pandas, is it a good idea to use pandas and arcpy jointly?